# Setting a GitHub Action environment variable with bash before reusable workflow

Tags: bash, github, yaml, environment-variables, action

I have scoured the forums and couldn't find a solution.

I have a config.yml file which contains a set of key/value pairs. One of those pairs I want to set as a GITHUB_ENV to be used in my workflow. But I am running into issues as the logs say

> "reusable workflows should be referenced at the top-level
> `jobs.*.uses' key, not within steps"

How do I get around this?

```
name: "Deploy The Kraken"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  call-build:
    steps:
      - name: Set env
        run: |
          echo "FEATURE_BRANCH=$(cat config.yml  | awk -F: '/^branch:/ { print $2 }'
          | sed 's/ //g')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Test
        run: echo $FEATURE_BRANCH

      - uses: ######/#####/.github/workflows/kraken.yml@$FEATURE_BRANCH
        with:
          environment: #####
          workspace: #####
          contract: #####
          production-ref: #####
```

I have tried multiple variations of placing the shell command in different parts. But I still can't get it to point to my chosen branch.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call a reusable workflow as a step, unfortunately. See a more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75735736/9741604