# GitHub Actions: How to call a reusable workflow as a step?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a main GitHub Actions workflow that is triggered via the `workflow_dispatch` event, and a reusable workflow that is triggered via the `workflow_call` event.

Is it possible to run a reusable workflow via a step in your main workflow and not as a job?

Main workflow:

```yaml
name: main-workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      message:
       type: string
       description: 'A message to pass to reusable workflow'

jobs:
  use-reusable-workflow:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Call reusable workflow
        uses: my-org/reusable-workflow@main
        with:
          workflow: reusable-workflow.yml
          inputs: |
            message=${{ github.event.inputs.message }}
          secrets: |
            A_SECRET: ${{ secrets.A_SECRET }}
```

When running the main workflow I am getting the following error:

> Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under

Comment: `Is it possible to run a reusable workflow via a step in your main workflow and not as a job?`. You can't. However, you could use a [local action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-public-action-in-a-subdirectory) in that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [GitHub official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow):

> You call a reusable workflow by using the uses keyword. Unlike when you are using actions within a workflow, you call reusable workflows directly within a job, and not from within job steps.

Therefore, **you can't call a reusable workflow from a job `step`**.

---

A workaround in your case could be using a [local action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-public-action-in-a-subdirectory), which basically allows you to use an action in the same repository as the workflow.

**Example of a local action call:**

```
jobs:
  my_first_job:
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use local my-action
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
```

*Note that you need to inform the path to the directory that contains the action in your workflow's repository. Therefore, to access the action file, you must check out your repository before using the action with the `actions/checkout`.*

This local action could be a [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action), similar to what a reusable workflow could achieve using actions, scripts or shell commands. I recommend [this article to understand the difference between composite actions and reusable workflows](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/composite-actions-vs-reusable-workflows-what-is-the-difference-github-actions-11kd).

Comment: Calling a local reusable workflow as a step doesn't work for me. I check out the repo, confirm the action path exists via `ls`, and it fails to run with  `Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/runner/_work/my_repo/my_repo/.github/workflows/actionName'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?`

It sounds like it *must* be a composite action to run as a step, not *could* be.

Comment: what I've had to do as a result is create three jobs when one should have been sufficient - a checkout job (because otherwise job #2 is not found), then a job that runs the local reusable workflow, and finally a job that actually does my task.

Comment: Do you mean local reusable workflow, or local action? Any reusable workflow can be call from another workflow at the job level, however o local action (composite, docker or javascript) needs the actions/checkout first to be used at the step level.

Comment: Local reusable workflow, run from the checkout using a relative path. `Error: .github#L1 reusable workflows should be referenced at the top-level `jobs.*.uses' key, not within steps`

Comment: I tried referencing from the repo with a dynamic tag, and that didn't work because `inputs` wasn't available at that context