# Is there a way to call a workflow that is part of the submodule repo from the main application repo in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a  main "application" repo which has .github folder
And i have added a submodule "test" repo to the main "application" repo which also has a .github folder.

Is there a way to call the (workflow file of submodule "test" repo ) from the workflow file of the application repo using GITHUB Actions?

Any insigths would be helpful?

the start.yml file in the aplication repo has reference to the workflow in submodule repo

```
  cicd:
     needs: [core]
     uses: ./Devops/.github/workflows/devops-core-cicd.yml
     with:
         repo_name: ${{ github.repository }}  
         postcheckout: ${{ needs.core.outputs.par_postcheckout }}
```

**invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/fi-devops-app-start.yml#L125
invalid value workflow reference: no version specified**

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include that in your question. Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible natively, however you could be using a [local action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-public-action-in-a-subdirectory), which basically allows you to use an action.yaml in the same repository as the workflow. If this action.yaml substitute a workflow (being a composite action) you will be able to perform the same operations. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75733616/github-actions-how-to-call-a-reusable-workflow-as-a-step/75735736#75735736) might help. (other option is to separate repos)