# How to execute a workflow_call only when the PR is Merged and in the master?

Tags: github, github-actions

I created a flow called ci-cd, in this guy we have the following code:

```
name: WORKFLOW CONTROLLER [CI/CD]

on: [workflow_dispatch, pull_request]

jobs:
  linters:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/linters.yml
  deploy:
    needs: linters
    uses: ./.github/workflows/githubpages.yml
```

In this code I want to do the following, whenever a pull_request is opened it will run the linters to check if everything is ok, passing this test, the merge to the PR in the master is released.

When merging the PR into the master, it must run the github pages deploy flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case can be achieved by using the [`pull_request` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore) with the `types` field for the `on` key in the workflow file. The `types` field can be used to specify which activity types for the `pull_request` event should trigger the workflow.

`workflow_call` is a type of event that can be used in a GitHub Actions workflow file to allow for another workflow to call it.

The `uses` keyword within a job in a workflow file is typically used to refer to a specific action, not another workflow.

If you want to have the linters and deploy workflows triggered as part of the CI/CD workflow, you could define them as reusable workflows, and then you can use the `uses` keyword to call these workflows in your main CI/CD workflow.

```yaml
name: WORKFLOW CONTROLLER [CI/CD]

on: 
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, closed]

jobs:
  linters:
    uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/linters.yml@branch
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed'
    
  deploy:
    uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/githubpages.yml@branch
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    needs: linters
```

With `org/repo/.github/workflows/linters.yml@branch` and `org/repo/.github/workflows/githubpages.yml@branch` placeholders for the actual repository and branch where your reusable workflows are located.

However, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75735736/6309), you cannot call a reusable workflow from a job step.

Comment: As the "linters" and "deploy" jobs are on: workflow_call, wouldn't it be necessary in the ci-cd file above to insert the on: workflow_call ?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS Got it. I have rewritten the workflow accordingly.